# Is a menstruating woman allowed to eat non-veg during auspicious timings?

Tags: scripture, women, non-vegetarian, menstruation

It is mentioned in scriptures that one should not eat non-veg food during certain times such as Amavasya, Pournami, Sunday, Ekadasi etc.,

**According to scriptures, is it applicable for menstruating women also?**

I got this doubt because of the reason that women are generally not obliged to follow many routine/scriptural rituals during menstrual time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is instruction in the Smritis that she should not eat meat during that period.

> A menstruating woman remains impure for three days. 7 She should not
> apply collyrium on her eyes or oil on her body, or bathe in water; she
> should sleep on the floor and not sleep during the day; **she should**
> **not** touch the fire, make a rope, brush her teeth, **eat meat**, or look at the planets; she should not laugh, do any work, or run; and
> she should drink out of a large pot or from her cupped hands or a
> copper vessel. 8 For it is stated: ‘Indra, after he had killed the
> three-headed son of Tvastr ˚ , was seized by sin, and he regarded
> himself in this manner .........
>
> **Dharmasutras of Vashishta 5.6-8**